# How to take password as input from user in hidden form in sql?

Tags: oracle, passwords

Is it possible to take input of password from user in hidden form in sql?
As we enter any character immediately it should get replaced by * .

When we try to connect with oracle as we can't see our password like that way i want to take input from user.

Comment: What "Form" are you talking about?

Comment: Actually i am developing a banking project in which i want to hide pin entered by user

Comment: This has nothing to do with Oracle. Oracle is a database where you store data, it does not provide any interface to the client (maybe apart from `sqlplus`). If you start `sqlplus` without password then it will prompt for it and does not show it in clear text.